# Apache modrewrite for vhost applies to all vhosts

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I have three separate dvhost configurations on sites-available and one of them contains:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$ /app/login.axvw [R]
```

The major problem is that it redirects all other vhost roots to /app/login.axvw too.

Full vhost conf:

Edit. Added full conf of one vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    ServerAlias sub.domain

        redirect / https://sub.domain.com/app/login.axvw

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sub.domain_error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sub.domain_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName sub.domain.com

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/domain.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl.key/domain.com.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/gd_bundle.crt

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$ /app/login.axvw [R]

#       redirect / https://sub.domain.com/app/login.axvw
    ProxyRequests Off

    ProxyPass / ajp://sub.domain.com:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://sub.domain.com

    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sub.domain_error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sub.domain_access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you post the complete configuration if convenient?

Comment: I must add that this is name based setup for vhosts. Server has one IP.

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the rewrite and use Redirectmatch instead; save your sanity for when things get *really* interesting.

```
Redirectmatch ^/$ https://sub.domain.com/app/login.axvw
```

Comment: This causes same problem.
When I have sub2.domain.com then it's root is redirected to /app/login.axvw